# Remote validation attribute in MVC3 invalid get format

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, remote-validation

I trying to use remote validation for the first time, but am encountering problems with the parameters passed inot the remote validation method.

My model is as follows:

```
public class PerinatalWomanView : IPerinatalWoman
{
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The woman's postcode is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Woman's postcode")]
    [Remote("PostcodeCheck", "Validation", "Validation")]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z]{1,2}[0-9][0-9A-Za-z]{0,1} [0-9][A-Za-z]{2}$", ErrorMessage = "A valid postcode is required")]
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
```

The view snippet is:

```
<div class="editor-label control-label">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.perinatalWomanView.Postcode)
</div>
div class="editor-field controls">
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.perinatalWomanView.Postcode)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.perinatalWomanView.Postcode)
</div>
```

and the validation controller is:

```
public class ValidationController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Validation/Validation/

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult PostcodeCheck(string Postcode)
    {

        //  postcode has already been checked for correct format
        //  now look it up to see if it exists

        string mbrraceCommonCodeEntitiesConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MbrraceCommonCodeEntities"].ConnectionString;
        if (PostcodeChecks.CheckPostcodeExists(mbrraceCommonCodeEntitiesConnectionString, Postcode))
        { return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); }

        return Json("This postcode was not found in the database", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

When the controller is called the value of Postcode is null. The actual call - from Firebug - is:

```
http://localhost:57881/Validation/Validation /PostcodeCheck?perinatalWomanView.Postcode=OX4+1SU
```

How do I read the postcode string parameter correctly becuase it is clearly not null?

HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a view model like this:

```
public class AddressViewModel
{
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
}
```

and then use specify the [`Prefix`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute.prefix.aspx) by decorating the parameter with the [`[Bind]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PostcodeCheck(
    [Bind(Prefix = "perinatalWomanView")]AddressViewModel model
)
{
    // use model.Postcode here ...
}
```

or if you don't want to use the `Bind` attribute have the following models:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public AddressViewModel PerinatalWomanView { get; set; }
}

public class AddressViewModel
{
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your controller action take the view model:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PostcodeCheck(MyViewModel model)
{
    // use model.PerinatalWomanView.Postcode here ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that (PostcodeCheck([Bind(Prefix = "perinatalWomanView")]string Postcode)) but Postcode is still null. I am extremely puzzled.

Comment: Try the second approach, it's better and it will most definitely work. I will see why the first doesn't work and update my answer accordingly. But now I have to run.